# How to disable webpack dev server auto reload for neutrino project?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, neutrino

- Browser: Peruse
- Type of project: SAFE network website

I need to turn it off because Peruse considers `window.eval()` to be a security issue and thus blocks it, which in turn stops my website from loading.

Peruse is the standard browser for Maidsafe as far as I know.

Both of my attempts to fix this have failed:

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    inline: false
  }
};
```

*neutrinorc.js*

```
module.exports = {
  use: [
    [
      '@neutrinojs/vue',
      {
        html: {
          title: 'SAFE Web App'
        }
      }
    ],
    (neutrino) => {
      neutrino.config.devServer
        .hot(false)
        .inline(false)
    }
  ]
};
```

The error:

```
Uncaught Error: Sorry, peruse does not support window.eval().
    at window.eval.global.eval (/opt/Maidsafe/Peruse/resources/app.asar/webPreload.js:9:82219)
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:5000 (http://localhost:5000/index.js:957:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:5000/index.js:679:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:5000/index.js:89:20)
    at Object.0 (http://localhost:5000/index.js:1060:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:5000/index.js:679:30)
    at http://localhost:5000/index.js:725:37
    at http://localhost:5000/index.js:728:10
```

*package.json*

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-module-imports": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
    "vue": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@neutrinojs/vue": "^8.2.1",
    "@vue/devtools": "^4.1.5",
    "neutrino": "^8.2.1"
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eval()` errror is not coming from webpack-dev-server.

It turns out that the the default source map mode used by `@neutrinojs/web` which `@neutrinojs/web` inherits from is `cheap-module-eval-source-map` and needs to be set to `cheap-module-source-map`.

Thus *neutrinorc.js* needs to be configured as such:

```
module.exports = {
  use: [
    ['@neutrinojs/vue', {
      // Existing options
    }],
    (neutrino) => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        // Override the default development source map of 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
        // to one that doesn't use `eval` (reduces incremental build performance).
        neutrino.config.devtool('cheap-module-source-map');
      }
    }
  ]
};
```